# AWS RDS and TIG

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, grafana, metrics

I just have a question about if its possible to query AWS RDS somehow and get this data into Telegraf/influxdb to be shown in grafana?

I have used to TIG stack before but only really to show cloudwatch metrics. I have been looking online and am getting a little lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks all.

Comment: Why you can't configure RDS (MySQL/PostgreSQL/...) datasource in the Grafana?

Answer (score 1):

You can't query metrics directly from AWS RDS. You can use AWS CloudWatch to monitor the metrics of AWS RDS database. Then use AWS CloudWatch as a datasource and import it to Grafana Dashboard.
Let's see official documentation for more detail

- RDS Dashboard: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/707
- Documentation: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/

Cheers.

Comment: Question is "how to query AWS RDS", not "how to query AWS CloudWatch RDS metrics".